# Executing a command from C++, What is expected in argv[0]?

Tags: c++, linux, argument-passing, execv

I am using `execv()` to run commands from /bin/ such as 'ls', 'pwd', 'echo' from my c++ program, and I am wondering what value I should provide in argv[0];

```
const char * path = getPath();
char ** argv = getArgs();

execv(path,argv);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`argv[0]` is supposed to be the program name. It's passed to the program's `main` function. Some programs differentiate their behavior depending on what string `argv[0]` is. For example the GNU `bash` shell will disable some of its features if called using `sh` instead of `bash`. Best give it the same value that you pass to `path`.

In linux, `argv[0]` is the process name displayed by the `top` utility (which it probably gets from reading entries in `/proc/`)

Comment: Most shells will run the profile if argv[0] is preceded by a dash, as in '`-sh`' or '`-ksh`'.  This also works with 'bash' disguised as 'sh' and as itself.  It is how the login process requests shells to run the profile.

Answer (score 5):

argv[0] should be the full path of the command that you want to run.

Comment: There is no obligation for it to be the full pathname; indeed, the value does not have to be related to the name of the executable at all.  It is convenient if it is, but you absolutely cannot rely on it being the full pathname.

Answer (score 2):

I know that this is not the answer you're looking for but is there a specific reason why you're doing this? The reason I ask is that most if not all of the actions people normally run with either `system()` or `execv()` are available in libraries on either Windows or Unix and are safer, faster and less likely to suffer from *circumstantial* errors. By that I mean, for example, when the `PATH` changes and suddenly your code stops working.

If you're passing in a string, either in whole or in part, and running it then you also leave yourself open to a user gaining access to the system by entering a command that could be damaging. E.g. imagine you've implemented a file search using `find /home -name` and your user types in:

```
"%" -exec rm {} \;
```

Ouch!

Comment: It was for a homework assignment where I had to create my own simple shell, and I was required to use evecv();

Comment: Point taken. Not perhaps the best subject matter for a homework assignment. Presumably your tutor is at some point going to cover defensive programming? If not, perhaps you could / should suggest that he / she does? Good luck with it in any case - I wish they'd had stackoverflow when I was at college!